# How do I get more tips in Tiny Tower?

Tags: ios, tiny-tower

Occasionally when I deliver someone to a floor via elevator they'll tip me one Bux. It can be difficult to stop the elevator exactly at the proper floor without any downward elevator adjustments, but it feels like I get tips more often when I get it just right. That said, I don't get tipped *every* time I get it perfect.

Am I just making it up or does one really get more tips for delivering customers to the proper floors with perfect accuracy?

Comment: I think it's just psychological, and the tips are completely random.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, it's random.

I once left a guy waiting in the lift on the lobby floor for roughly 30 seconds (without realising it), overshot by nearly one floor, and still got tipped.

How accurate you are with the lift does not affect what you get - whether you hit the floor spot on or overshoot by a floor, you still get your coin tip of (2 * Destination Floor Level) and if the RNG is nice to you, a Tower Bux tip.

If perfect accuracy did affect the chances of you getting tipped, it would be abused.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that accuracy DOES affect tips. I've been doing this for ages, and I've managed to become pretty accurate. I get tips around 60% of the time I'm accurate so yeah... I think it does affect. Otherwise, Idk how I'm getting so many tips LOL. After I upgraded my elevator I never got tips anymore cos its harder to be accurate when the elevator is uuber fast

Answer (score -1):

I think it's random, but at the same time, it does appear that I get more tips the more accurate I am.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer repeats an existing answer. Use your votes and comments to respond to those answers before making your own.

Answer (score -4):

I think you get tipped when you perform perfectly.